# IIS7 Web Farm Framework 2.0 Basic Setup Questions On Load Balancing

Tags: iis-7, web-farm

Pardon the basic questions but I can't seem to find any basic answers.

I'm in the process of standing up a standard server farm using Web Farm Framework 2.0. I set up a controller server and a primary server. When I provisioned my primary server I did so enabling load balancing. I then deployed a basic MVC application on my primary server. I am able to ping my client application when I hit the primary server directly confirming everything is OK on that end. For the sake of kicking tires, what I'd like to do is access that same MVC application through my farm.

For clarity, let's say my environment looks like this: controller (IP: 192.168.0.1), primary (IP: 192.168.0.2).

To access the MVC application through the farm, what address should I be pointing to? I assumed it would be 192.168.0.1/mymvcapplication however that does not work. Keep in mind, by-passing the load balancer (which I presume is my controller server) works fine. Am I missing something in terms of enabling load balancing? Is there something else I'm required to do (on my controller or primary server) beyond just checking the Enable Load Balancing checkbox when provisioning the primary server?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to check. You need to make sure that the routing is setup correctly. I had a problem similar where I had a host name setup in the controller website and it wasn't routing the requests over to the URLRewrite module.

Try these:

1. Verify the site is "Available" and "Load Balanced"
2. Verify the health monitor is setup to a correct url (bad health monitoring will stop the site)
3. Verify the Controller doesn't have any host name bindings or URLRewrites
4. Verify the Server URLRewrite routes to the server farm

Also, I would try just a static "Hello World" page too, sometimes there are app issues that get in the way (But you said you tested and worked fine).